# Kendo UI toggle text as html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am trying to make it so my kendo text box can display the contents of the text box as html. If the user enters html and clicks the option it will show them how the contents looks as html.

I am using kendo to make a text box with multiple options.

Here is an image of what it displays like

[image]

Here is the code to create the text box

```
<div class="editor-field">
   @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.BlogText)
        .ImageBrowser(imageBrowser => imageBrowser
        .Image("~/Content/UserFiles/Images/{0}")
        .Read("Read", "ImageBrowser")
        .Create("Create", "ImageBrowser")
        .Destroy("Destroy", "ImageBrowser")
        .Upload("Upload", "ImageBrowser")
        .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser"))
   )
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BlogText)
</div>
```

I see there is a method in the EditorBuilder class in the Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent called Encode

```
// Summary:
//     Encode HTML content.
public EditorBuilder Encode(bool value);
```

I am not sure if thats the way to enable html encoding

**Update**

I need to add the View HTML button. Just need to figure out how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to View HTML. There is a tools sections and there is a ViewHtml tool

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.BlogText)
    .Tools(tools => tools
       .ViewHtml())
    .ImageBrowser(imageBrowser => imageBrowser
    .Image("~/Content/UserFiles/Images/{0}")
    .Read("Read", "ImageBrowser")
    .Create("Create", "ImageBrowser")
    .Destroy("Destroy", "ImageBrowser")
    .Upload("Upload", "ImageBrowser")
    .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser"))
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works for "special characters" that may not be considered valid with the standard character set like <> for example! I don't think this is what you were looking for.